# Google App Engine - Apply security constraint only to POST method?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, servlets, authorization

I am building a web application using GAE in Java. I am facing a problem in applying a `<security-constraint>` in the web.xml only to the POST method of a servlet.

Here is the relevant portion of my web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>data</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/data</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

So I want to enforce authentication only when the POST method is called. The GET method should be allowed for all users.

I tested the above code and it works fine in the localhost development server. But when I actually deploy it to App Engine, it does not work. It requires authentication even for the GET method of the 'data' Servlet. Whenever I try the GET method on the above URL, I get a 302 found response with the authentication URL in the response headers. It seems GAE is applying the security constraint to both the GET and POST methods instead of just the POST method.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have have to POST to the same Java App then add a separate url pattern. ie /data1. Then put the security constraint on that pattern. I tried this and it worked:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JavaAppName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/data1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>JavaAppName</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/data1</url-pattern>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>admin</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
```

Just make sure to update the HTML POST to the right target.

Ideally you should split the GET and POST into separate files.